# My CPU consumption is very high because Express JS is sending too many requests

Tags: node.js, express, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, m3u8

I am broadcasting live on my site and I am doing these live broadcasts through the m3u8 file. I'm pulling the m3u8 file on the remote server with the code block I've sent below and giving the link to my video player.

```
request(m3u8Url, async function (error, response, body) { 
 if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
 await fs.writeFileSync(`public/Uploads/Live/channel1.m3u8`,body);
 await fs.createReadStream(`public/Uploads/Live/channel1.m3u8`).pipe(res);}});
```

Then, to hide the link on the remote server, you can use the outgoing links on your own.

```
var newurl = `${parseURL.protocol}//${parseURL.host}` + setNewURL; 

 request(newurl).pipe(res)
```

When I do this I get a working build with 100% certainty. When the number of users logging into my website is 50+, my cpu usage increases too much.

I tried to redirect the requests from the original url instead of my own site, but again my cpu consumption was too high.

Comment: Don't use `writeFileSync` on the server. That's OK for command line applications but should never be used for server code or GUI applications. That's because it blocks the interpreter from handling other events.

Comment: Are you using any cache system or CDN? Better to make use of them too.

Comment: So is there anything wrong with this code? If I use writeFile instead of writeFileSync, will my problem still persist? @slebetman

Comment: There’s not enough context. When do you pull the file?

Comment: I don't use any cdn, frankly I don't know how to redirect the link over cdn. I would be very grateful if you could provide a cdn company you can recommend and a resource on how to run it. @Asadullah

Comment: File creation and reading work when the player is started. The query determines which link will work. /For example: live?channel=abcTv This link is sent to the player and the incoming channel query receives the link of that channel and starts processing. @DaveNewton

Comment: @leshcode Why do you want to "hide" the original URL?  Can you simply redirect to it, thereby removing almost all of the load from your server in the first place?  And, why are you caching this to disk if you're just turning around and reading it again?  Why not stream?  And if you are just proxying content, why not just configure a standard performant server like Nginx instead of reinventing it?

Comment: Hello @Brad, the original url is a private url for me and when they click on that url, it stops broadcasting on my site. I need to hide the url because I make the broadcast publicly.

Comment: So, you need to configure Nginx as a caching proxy then.

Comment: @Brad Thank you for answering! Is there any documentation on this subject?

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/